# Recursion error in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n==1 | n==2:
        return 1
    f = (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2))
    return f
```

Hi, I'm a python newbie and I want to implement a recursive fibonacci function, but my code (above) does not work. When I call this function the terminal prints the 6th line until the recursion depth limit is reached. What's the correct syntax to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make very small change => `|` to `or`

(Arithmetic OR to Logical OR)

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n==1 or n==2:
        return 1
    f = (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2))
    return f


print fibonacci(6)
# 8
```

Another option is to use `if (n==1)|(n==2):` on line 4

hope it helps : )

Answer (score 1):

"|" is a arithmetic or, not a logic. Use "or"

```
   def fibonacci(n):
        if n==0:
            return 0
        if n==1 or n==2:
            return 1
        f = (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2))
        return f
```